# Tabs missing after letter c in numbered list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a really wierd error in Word 2013. I have a numbered list (guessing, that's what it's called in English) with two levels. The first level is numbered with numbers, the second is numbered with small letters. After every number there should be a tab, and it is everywhere except after the letter c. The whole thing looks like this:

```
1.    Text
    a.    Text
    b.    Text
    c.Text
    d.    Text
2.    Text
    a.    Text
    b.    Text
    c.Text
    d.    Text
```

It only occurs after a `c.`
Any idea what can cause that and how to get rid of this?

Answer (score 0):

Copy format from the paragraph b. to the paragraph c. to fix this issue.

I think there is a tab in this line, but tab stop positions are set differently than in other lines. You can verify this in Tabs dialog box (reachable from Paragraph dialog box) for line b. and line c. A numbered list uses tab settings of paragraphs where it is created.